# Java - Can I add business logic in Builder methods?

Tags: java, builder, business-logic

I am currently working on refactoring the code in our web application and I ran into a very complex object that needs to be built from multiple objects. Each attribute of the complex object is derived by executing some logic. I searched online to find a clean solution to refactor the creation of this complex object and finally settled on Builder pattern. Below is an example to illustrate how I approached it.

**Account Object**

```
public class Account {
  private String accountNumber;
  private Boolean eligible;
  private Double balance;

  public Account(Account.Builder builder) {
    accountNumber = builder.accountNumber;
    eligible = builder.eligible;
    balance = builder.balance;
  }

  public String getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
  }

  public Boolean isEligible() {
    return eligible;
  }

  public Double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public static class Builder {
    private String accountNumber;
    private Boolean eligible;
    private Double balance;

    public static Builder builder() {
       return new Builder();
    }

    Builder withAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
       this.accountNumber = accountNumber; // Simple assignment
       return this;
    }

    Builder withEligibility(Promotion promotion, CustomerType customerType) {
      // Run logic on the promotion and the type of customer to determine if the customer is eligible and then set the eligible attribute
       return this;
    }

    Builder withBalance(Promotion promotion, CustomerExpenses expenses) {
       // Run logic on the promotion and the customer expenses to determine the balance amount and set it to balance attribute
       return this;
    }

    Account build() {
       return new Account(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Is this approach right? I am getting some pushback from my colleagues that you shouldn't do logic in builder methods. I want to know if I am moving in the right direction. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion the with-methods should not contain logic beyond basic transformations (same as a setter). If you want to have business logic in a builder it should be in the `build()` method (or private methods called from it).

Comment: Then the logic would again be accumulated in a single method (in this case, build() method). That is how it is today in the existing code. All building logic in one method. I wanted to organize it better by refactoring it. Is there any other pattern I can look into to fit this requirement?

Comment: First of all. Why are you using the Builder pattern? Looks more like you have a simple object, and business logic polluting the creation of that object.

Comment: The object I have given in the above code is an example. The actual object I am trying to build has 168 attributes, each attribute has some logic to derive it. I am ok with using any other pattern that would help me organize this code in a meaningful manner.

Comment: Also I took a look at `StringBuilder` in java api which has a the logic in the builder methods that is required to build the `String`